# VirtualBox VM with dedicated nic

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, network-adapter

I have two NICs on my host machine: `eno1` and `eno2`.
Both of these are connected to the same LAN and subnet, but with the intention that `eno1` will only be used by the host OS, and `eno2` will be dedicated to the guest VM.

I did find some info on https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=70273 which states
Yes you can do that, but you do it from the network settings in the host, not in VirtualBox.

> On the card which the host uses, clear the check mark from the box for
> VirtualBox NDIS Bridged Networking Driver. This reserves this NIC for
> the host. On the card which the guest uses, clear all the checkboxes
> except the bridged networking driver. Only the vm can use this NIC.

However, I am having trouble finding info on how to do this from commandline, as I run everything on a headless server. How do I achieve this with `vboxmanage` ?

Host OS: Debian

Guest: Also Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Network-Manager` is probably where you should be looking at. First find `eno2`'s MAC address with something like `ip link show eno2`. Open with an editor `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and at the end of the file two lines:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:00:11:22:aa:bb:cc
```

where `00:11:22:aa:bb:cc` is the MAC address of eno2. After restarting, eno2 should be left on its own and you can then manage it from VirtualBox.

Comment: Taking custody away from network manager is what did the trick.